# Lazarus Style Help about form

Tags: lazarus

I need to create an about entry for a Lazarus project.  I would like it to be a multi page affair like the about one in the Lazarus IDE but I cannot find any information about doing so.

Comment: Isn't that simply a tpagecontrol?

Comment: And you could also open `lazarus/ide/aboutfrm.pas` in Lazarus to see how it's done there (and F12 to see the form).

Answer (score 0):

The one in the Lazarus about box and what I also use for many of my projects is a TTabControl.  What I find particularly useful is to use this in conjunction with a [TRichMemo](http://wiki.freepascal.org/RichMemo) and then have different RTF files for each tab that are then compiled into the program as resources.

For example, for one project I have four tabs.  I use the caption for each tab as part of the name of the resource for that tab.  My resource file for it looks like this:

```
ABOUTBOX_INSTRUCTIONS   RCDATA  "Resources/Instructions.rtf"              LANGUAGE 0,0
ABOUTBOX_LICENSE        RCDATA  "Resources/License.rtf"                   LANGUAGE 0,0
ABOUTBOX_CHANGELOG      RCDATA  "Resources/Changelog.rtf"                 LANGUAGE 0,0
ABOUTBOX_CREDITS        RCDATA  "Resources/Credits.rtf"                   LANGUAGE 0,0
```

Switching tabs then becomes relatively easy to do:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// tabAboutTabs OnChange event handler.  Load the appropriate resource into
// the RichMemo box.
//
procedure TAboutBox.tabAboutTabsChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResourceStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  // Each tab's caption becomes part of the resource name for the RTF file loaded.
  ResourceStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'ABOUTBOX_' + UpperCase(tabAboutTabs.Tabs[tabAboutTabs.TabIndex]), RT_RCDATA);
  richAboutText.LoadRichText(ResourceStream);
  ResourceStream.Free;
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This gives you the ability to have a multi-tab help form with nicely formatted text you can generate with a word processor that is embedded right inside your executable.